# Selenium gets stuck on .get(url)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a website with a login field, and if I close the driver and re-open it every time (logging in every time), then it works fine, but if I try to continue using the same driver then it gets stuck on the .get(url) request.

```
DRIVER = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()

def login(url):
   DRIVER.get(url)
   username = DRIVER.find_element_by_name('login')
   password = DRIVER.find_element_by_name('passwd')
   username.send_keys('justinalexander')
   password.send_keys('sin4546')
   form = DRIVER.find_element_by_name('blogin')
   form.click()
   time.sleep(5)
return

def main():
   login(url)
   data = DRIVER.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
   print("1")
   DRIVER.get(url2) # this page does open in the chrome window
   print("2") # code never reaches here
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the login is successful? 2. Does the selenium driver save the login session cookie?

Comment: 1) Yes, the second page (that does load in the chrome window) wouldn't load if I wasn't logged in. Plus, if I close the driver each time and create a new one, then it loads everything no problem. 2) How would I go about doing that/checking?

Comment: I tried saving the cookies, but it still doesn't solve the problem. It loads the page fine on the first driver.get(url) call, but it timeouts on the second driver.get(url) call.

Comment: I figured out a workaround that I'm satisfied with for the time being, but I'm having another problem. There are 150 pages I need to check and they're of the form "base_url&page=X". But when I call driver.get("base_url&page=x") it strips off the '&page=x' for some reason.

Comment: Web parameters are with a ? in the beginning of the parameter list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: There are other parameters that it doesn't strip off though. Regardless, how should I handle web parameters then?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html use urllib.urlencode